# Where can I find a list of past flights at LHR?

Tags: airport

I am doing a project based on some data recorded from London Heathrow during October 2012, to quality control the data I need to know when aircraft flew past the detectors.

Are there any online databases of when flights took off and landed at Heathrow during this period?

If the data contains which runway the aircraft landed on that would also be desirable,

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

If you're lucky, you might just get it for free (see [halfway down this page](http://www.flightstats.com/go/About/businessSolutions.do)):

> We have provided a data drop of historical flight information for
>   specific airports or airlines, on a one-off basis.

As for the runway data, it's harder, since I don't know of any website which records it. You can have a look on [Flightradar24](http://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/lhr) for which runway is in use at the moment depending on the aircraft positions, but apart from that it's probably not going to be easy. You might want to email the airport directly and ask if they could provide a figure for that month for each runway, but I'll doubt that a single source has the details for each and every flight.

If you get to it, have fun sorting out 40,000 flights ;)

Comment: Manfreds answer will hopefully help you  finding the data you need. On this website you can check which runway was in use that day, but!! only if you know if they were on east or west operations. There are probably enough stored weather data to find out ;) To me it sounds some kind of strange what you are doing - okay, I decided to fly planes rather than to study - but maybe you tell us the reson. Here you go:  http://www.plane-mad.com/airport-spotting-guides/united-kingdom/london-heathrow-lhr-egll.html?force-nonmobile=true#runway-alternation